# JavaFX 2 Window.hide after a specific time

Tags: java, window, javafx-2

I would like to close / hide the window after 30 seconds (or another
specific time). I tried a bit with this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.getTime().getTime();
```

but I couldn't really figure out how to get it to work. I'm using JavaFX 2. How can I specify an amount of time to wait before hiding the window with `window.hide()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a [PauseTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) is simple because it keeps everything on the JavaFX Application thread and you don't need to worry about potential threading issues.

If you are on Java 8:

```
final Window window = new Stage();
. . .
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(30));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> window.hide());
pause.play();
```

Or, if you are on Java 7, replace the lambda with:

```
pause.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        window.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ScheduledExecutorService to schedule the event, although on Java 8+ the other answer should be preferred:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.schedule(
     new Runnable() {
       @Override public void run() {
         Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
           @OVerride public void run() { stage.hide(); }
         })
       }
     }, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Please use `Platform.runLater()` to execute it on the GUI thread.